# Pi 3 B+, inerchange with zero

Tags: pi-zero

I have a Pi 3 B+, and a Zero coming. With the 3 B having wi-fi, and Bluetooth is it right thinking that it will be more convenient to program the chip in the 3 B, then take it out to put in the Zero for the application?

Comment: You can't remove the CPU from the Pi. I think you need to research the Pi and its hardware.

Comment: I think, when saying "take it out", the OP was referring to the SD card as "it" :p

Comment: Paul could you please edit the "take it out to put in" part to be unambiguous?